# Converting Sqrt and exp in result from letters to symbols in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a result just like this and i can't read it easily is there a way to view or print the result with symbols instead of this ?

[image]

Comment: [`pretty`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/pretty.html)?

Comment: Or [`latex`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/latex.html)?

Comment: Is it really that hard to type (or copy paste) the actual code into the question?  Why the need for pictures?

Comment: Or [live script](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/what-is-a-live-script.html)

Comment: Thx all , it is my first time to use Stack overflow , i am a beginner in using matlab , and i tried to search in google but could n't find the way

Answer (score 0):

Use [`latex`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/latex.html) to convert the symbolic expression to Latex-compatible string. Then use any latex editor to compile, or online tools like Overleaf or [this one](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php).